# Turn transactions data into sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to follow the workflow in the following question: [Converting from regular format to sparse format for arules package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912938/r-converting-from-regular-format-to-sparse-format-for-arules-package) . I have some transaction data and I would like to turn it into a sparse matrix that can be fed into the `arules` package. The solution to the posted question no longer works. See below:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11)
Item <- c("Avas", "Alo", "Erbi", "Abra", "Ali", "Inj", "Avas", "Avas")
(test <- data.frame(ID, Item))
  ID Item
  1 Avas
  2  Alo
  2 Erbi
  8 Abra
  8  Ali
  8  Inj
  9  Inj
 10 Avas
 11 Avas

trans1 <- as(split(test[, "Item"], test[, "ID"]), "transactions")

Error in as(split(test[, "Item"], test[, "ID"]), "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “list” to “transactions”
```

At the very least, I would like to convert the above format to the following format (which I could then transform to a `arules` readable object in some subsequent steps):

```
   V1    V2   V3
1  Avas
2  Alo   Erbi
8  Abra  Ali  Inj
9  Inj
10 Avas
11 Avas
```

Comment: What's the shape of the final product? If it is a sparse matrix then in what format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read.table(text=do.call(paste,aggregate(.~ID,test,paste,collapse = ' ')),fill=T,h=F)
  V1   V2   V3  V4
1  1 Avas         
2  2  Alo Erbi    
3  8 Abra  Ali Inj
4  9  Inj         
5 10 Avas         
6 11 Avas
```

You heed to ensure that your dataframe has only characters. If that is not the case, do

```
  test = rapply(test,as.character,'factors',how='replace')
```

also you can do:

```
reshape(transform(test,time=ave(ID,ID,FUN=seq_along)),idvar = 'ID',dir='wide')
  ID Item.1 Item.2 Item.3
1  1   Avas   <NA>   <NA>
2  2    Alo   Erbi   <NA>
4  8   Abra    Ali    Inj
7  9    Inj   <NA>   <NA>
8 10   Avas   <NA>   <NA>
9 11   Avas   <NA>   <NA>
```